# How to format a Pandas dataframe before write to excel using XLSXWriter

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I have a main dataframe called df1, from this df1 I take six different dataframes based on different conditions. Later I write all this to different excel sheets, So my excel sheet will have 6 sheets.

What I want to do is that I need to colour the column heading of A:D with one colour, E:H to another colour etc. But xlsx writer is already taking time without formatting the file so with formatting it could take much more time.

So I wonder if somehow I can set colour to df1 itself and when taking data from it, all the six df will already have the format property.

What is the best way to do this ?

Comment: U should show how u write to xlsx. maybe there is something to optimize about the slowness. I usually do the formatting stuff with VBA and just implement a button... I don't what u mean by setting a color to df1, pls give an example.

Comment: I mean if I colour the main df1 and all the six sub df are made from df1 only. So I can just colour once and all six will already have the format.

Comment: You color the column header in excel and not in the dataframe. That's why I don't understand what you mean by that. Don't be lazy and show us some sample code...

Comment: Ah, ok never used pandas styling. I'm not sure if it is already possible to write pandas stylings to xlsx. Maybe: https://github.com/webermarcolivier/xlsxpandasformatter

Comment: @incognito what module was the thing I was looking for! Thanks